# Precise axiomatic definition for the equality "=" as a binary relation

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, relations, axioms

**Question:** What is a simple yet precise definition for "=" as a binary relation?

**My try:**
I find two definitions for "equality relation" which seems to be contradictory.

The first one I learnt in school is that [equality is what is called an equivalence relation](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/cn.html#:%7E:text=Assume%20that%20equality%20is%20what,z%2C%20then%20x%20%3D%20z.), that is, it satisfies three axioms: Reflexivity, Symmetry, Transitivity.

The [second definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)) contains an axiom of extensionality.

The third definition I heard contains this additional axiom: $x=y$ implies $P(x)=P(y)$

---

Thanks to the comments, I also learnt a definition using first-order logics:

These equality axioms are:

1. Reflexivity.
2. Substitution for functions.
3. Substitution for formulas.

This is close to the things I am looking for. However, this definition looks weird as the second axiom is a special case of the third. Axiomatic system usually don't use redundant axioms.

Comment: The first two aren't definitions of equality: there are equivalence relations other than $=$ (consider "has the same parity as"), and the axiom of extensionality is a *characterization* of equality rather than a *definition* of it (okay, I suppose one could view $\in$ as more primitive than $=$ and then take extensionality as a definition of $=$ in terms of $\in$, but I personally don't buy that - if only because *non-extensional* set theories are also interesting).

Comment: Recently there was a similar query, [my anser there applies here also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4858026/equal-sign-meaning-in-equations-vs-functions/4859149#4859149)

Comment: You are right that equality is *an* equivalence relation, but it is not the only one of course.

Comment: in my experience, in logic, $=$ is often used to denote the identity relation, that is, $a=b$ iff $a$ and $b$ are the very same object. In turn, this implies every predicate possessed by $a$ is also possessed by $b$ and vice versa. The identity relation is an example (or instance) of an equivalence relation, but there are equivalence relations that are not identity relations.

Comment: *equality* is a basic concept of human language and thought. In mathematics, it can be formalized using [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

Comment: For equality in set theory see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223017/why-isnt-the-equal-sign-part-of-the-set-theory-language) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4325728/different-meanings-of-in-first-order-logic-and-in-set-theory)

Comment: See also [Defining equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546309/defining-an-equality)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree with your comments so what is a definition for equality?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for you comments. I only need a simple definition for "=".

Comment: @dodo -- IMO there can't be a single definition of the $=$ sign, rather a list of usage. (It's like the word "mean" where my dictionary shows 9 different explications.) As with the equality sign it's similar with the term _equality_ -- its meaning evolves from the context.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Your first link is similar to what I am trying to look for. Though I have one question: in your link, there are three axioms, and the second axiom is a special case of the third axiom. This is a bit weird, as axiomatic system usually don't use redundant axioms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Re your addendum to the question*.

Yes, the two [basic axioms for *equality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) are *reflexivity*: $x=x$, and *substitution for formulas*: $s = t \to (\varphi [s/z] \to \varphi [t/z])$.

Note that, using [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation), we have that reflexivity holds for *terms* whatever: $t=t$.

Now, if $f$ is a function symbol (assuming for simplicity that it is a unary function symbol) from reflexivity we have $f(x)=f(x)$.

Thus, having that $f(x)=f(x)$ is $(z=f(x))[f(x)/z]$ and $f(y)=f(x)$ is $(z=f(x))[f(y)/z]$ we can use *susbstitution* to get:

> $x=y \to f(x)=f(y)$.

The *substitution* property is crucial for *equality*: if the binary relation has *reflexivity, symmetry* and *transitivity* but lacks the substitution property its is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Comment: Many thanks! So there are two equivalent definitions: The first one is reflexivity+substitution for formulas. The other one is reflexivity+symmetry+transitivity+substitution for functions?

Comment: How is substitution for function relates to substitution for predicates ($x=y\implies P(x)=P(y)$)?

Comment: @dodo - subst for *predicate* is a case of subst for formulas: $x=y \to (P(x) \to P(y))$. If $P$ is a predicate symbol, $P(x)=P(y)$ is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this before. Good point!